# Updating variable pulled from api every x seconds

Tags: python, tkinter

What I'm trying to do is grabbing a number from an API and update that number every 60 seconds on screen with tkinter. I'm able to get to number through the API just fine, only having trouble with figuring out how to get it to update.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

def getInfo(call):
        r = requests.get(call)
        return r.json()

key = " "
uuid = " "
url = f"https://api.hypixel.net/player?key={key}&uuid={uuid}"
data = getInfo(url)
uhcWins = "UHC Wins: " + str(data["player"]["stats"]["Duels"]["uhc_duel_wins"])

root = Tk()
root.title('Test Title')
root.geometry("500x500")

my_frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=200)
my_frame.pack(pady=20, ipady=20, ipadx=20)

my_label = Label(my_frame, text=uhcWins, font=("Helvetica", 40), fg="#09d2f6")
my_label.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You'll need to use a timer.  You can use `root.after` to request a callback after N seconds, and in your callback make that same call again to get called back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `root.after` function. Here's how to implement:

```
root.after(<time in millisecond>,<function>)
```

For your code you can do this:

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

def getInfo():
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    my_label.config(text="UHC Wins: " + str(data["player"]["stats"]["Duels"]["uhc_duel_wins"]))
    root.after(60000,getInfo)
    #In every 60 second it will call the get info function and change the context of my_label

root = Tk()
root.title('Test Title')
root.geometry("500x500")

my_frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=200)
my_frame.pack(pady=20, ipady=20, ipadx=20)

my_label = Label(my_frame, font=("Helvetica", 40), fg="#09d2f6")
my_label.pack(pady=20)

key = " "
uuid = " "
url = f"https://api.hypixel.net/player?key={key}&uuid={uuid}"
data = getInfo()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. You need to use IntVar() and use set() method to set value of variable. Read this for more info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-setting-and-retrieving-values-of-tkinter-variable/)

```
from Tkinter import *

def start():
    Inv = Tk()
    Inv.geometry("200x200")
data =500 # value from API 
    stats = IntVar() 
stats.set(data) #Set values to 500
print stats.get() # this will print 500

    EtkI2=Label(Inv, textvariable=stats).pack()
 
    # change the stats value after 5 seconds
    Inv.after(5000, stats.set, 100)

    # start the event loop
    Inv.mainloop()


start()
```

Comment: I didn't found anything what is OP asking in your code! You are creating new window in every 5 second! And OP is asking to update the number. Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68538595/12446721)

Comment: also why are you using `Python2`? it is a deprecated version and also: 
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.